# Sentences beginning with verbs in -ing and -ed forms

Tags: participle-clauses, supplementation

I'm confused with these sentences. Can you point out what's wrong and what's correct for me?

> 1. **Heard** the voice, he responded immediately.
> 2. **Hearing** the voice, he responded immediately.

Comment: 1 would be fine if you put "having" in front of "heard" like this: Having heard the voice, he responded immediately.

Comment: Belongs in ELL Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't think this needs closing: in Latin, for example, both would be fine. Precisely why a past participle needs  'having'  while a past participle does not (but could, for example, be *on hearing*) is not obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Your #2 example is okay, but #1 needs work:

> *Heard the voice, he responded immediately.

"Heard" is either (1) a past tense form ("He heard the voice"), (2) a perfect participle ("He has heard the voice"), or (3) a passive participle ("The voice is heard").

For (1), you need to supply a subject, then use a subordinate conjunction to connect the two clauses:

> When he heard the voice, he responded immediately.

For (2), since it's a perfect, "have" must be supplied:

> Having heard the voice, he responded immediately.
>   When he had heard the voice, he responded immediately.

For (3), the passivized object (now a subject) must precede:

> When the voice was heard, he responded immediately.
>   ?? The voice heard, he responded immediately.
>   ? The voice having been heard, he responded immediately.

I've given my opinions about the acceptability of the examples with: asterisk for really bad, question mark for a little odd, two question marks for quite odd.